# CSS: provide different padding on the last element without need for multiple classes

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that contains three images, which are more or less 31% wide. The idea is to provide padding in-between. The last image should have no right padding, so that the three together are as wide as a larger image above.

Like so...

[image]

How can I specify a variant (selector or otherwise) class that simply knows that the image is in this last position? Any ideas, maybe using siblings, etc.

Comment: Without providing your HTML it's not possible to construct a selector that would answer your question (unless someone makes a really lucky guess).

Comment: I disagree. The question was asked in the most general terms for a reason. I realize that a lot of cases call for exact specifications, but this is not one of them. The answer I selected as 'best' is applicable in many scenarios. While I was looking for a specific response to my current issue, I also want to apply it generically in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) pseudo class.

```
.container_class > img:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

P.S - Aren't you spacing elements from each other with *margin* instead of *padding*?

Comment: Images can have padding.

Comment: @MrLister I know, but usually they also have borders etc so using padding to space between them is pretty odd.

Comment: I don't remember TBH. This is old code that I want to clean up. I've been using `+` quite a bit but haven't read about this selector before. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you can use the `+` selector.

```
img + img {
  padding-left:4px;
}
```

in that way, every image except the first will receive the left padding. And you won't have to write one style rule for all images and a separate style rule for only the last image.